# GWT: Why isn't my Cell's FieldUpdater working?

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform, celltable

I have a `GWT` `CellTable` that I have just moved from a `PopupPresenter` to a regular nested `PresenterWidget`. I am using GWTP.

Since moving it, the `FieldUpdater` on my `ButtonCell` is not calling the `update()` method at all. I have tried a test button and the same thing happens.

```
// edit offer
Column<OfferDto, String> buttonColumn = new Column<OfferDto, String>(new ButtonCell(IconType.PLUS, ButtonType.SUCCESS))
{
    @Override
    public String getValue(OfferDto object)
    {
        return "View/Edit";
    }
};
buttonColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<OfferDto, String>()
{
    @Override
    public void update(int index, OfferDto object, String value)
    {
        // NOTHING IN HERE IS BEING CALLED
        System.out.println("Update called in setFieldUpdater...");
        getUiHandlers().onAddCommsClick(index, object);
    }
});
table.addColumn(buttonColumn);
```

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing it. Other regular buttons in the same View still work OK, it's just the CellTable.

Comment: do you get any exception in the ChromeDevTools console ?

Comment: Not that I can see. There's nothing in the console except a few GWT.log messages

Comment: OK I have worked it out... there was an exception being thrown but for some reason it wasn't showing in the console before. I enabled some more logging in the chrome dev tools options so looks like I have it sussed now. Thanks!